# No Residuals With Numpy's Least Squares

Tags: python, numpy, statsmodels, least-squares, empty-list

I am trying to compute a [least squares](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html) problem in Numpy (i.e. Ordinary Least Squares (OLS) with Simple Regression) in order to find the corresponding R² value. However, **in some cases**, Numpy is returning an empty list for the residuals. Take the following **[over-determined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overdetermined_system)** example (*i.e. more equations than unknowns*) that illustrates this problem:

[image: OLS problem]

*(Note: There is **no** constant factor (i.e. intercept) (i.e. an initial column vector of all 1's), therefore the **Uncentered** Total Sum of Squares (TSS) will be used.)*

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[6, 6, 3], [40, 40, 20]]).T
y = np.array([0.5, 0.2, 0.6])

model_parameters, residuals, rank, singular_values = np.linalg.lstsq(A, y, rcond=None)

# No Intercept, therefore use Uncentered Total Sum of Squares (TSS)
uncentered_tss = np.sum((y)**2)  
numpy_r2 = 1.0 - residuals / uncentered_tss

print("Numpy Model Parameter(s): " + str(model_parameters))
print("Numpy Sum of Squared Residuals (SSR): " + str(residuals))
print("Numpy R²: " + str(numpy_r2))
```

The following produces the following output:

```
Numpy Model Parameter(s): [0.00162999 0.01086661]
Numpy Sum of Squared Residuals (SSR): []
Numpy R²: []
```

According to the [numpy documentation](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/4457):

> ... residuals will be empty when the equations are under-determined or well-determined but return values when they are over-determined.

**However**, this problem is clearly over-determined (3 equations vs. 2 unknowns). I can even show that the residuals (and thereby the [sum of squared residuals (SSR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residual_sum_of_squares)) exist by computing the [regression results](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResults.html) given by the [statsmodels's OLS function](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.html):

```
import statsmodels.api as sm

A = np.array([[6, 6, 3], [40, 40, 20]]).T
y = np.array([0.5, 0.2, 0.6])

statsmodel_model = sm.OLS(y, A)
regression_results = statsmodels_model.fit()

calculated_r_squared = 1.0 - regression_results.ssr / np.sum((y)**2)

print("Parameters: " + str(regression_results.params))
print("Residuals: " + str(regression_results.resid))
print("Statsmodels R²: " + str(regression_results.rsquared))
print("Manually Calculated R²: " + str(calculated_r_squared))
```

The following produces the following output:

```
Parameters: [0.00162999 0.01086661]
Residuals: [ 0.05555556 -0.24444444  0.37777778]
Statsmodels R²: 0.6837606837606838
Manually Calculated R²: 0.6837606837606838
```

(*As you can see, the Statsmodels and Numpy models have agreeing parameters.*)

**Why does Numpy return an empty SSR array with the following example? Is this a bug with [numpy.linalg.lstsq](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html)?** If this is **not** a bug, then why is [Statsmodels](http://www.statsmodels.org/stable/index.html) able to compute the [sum of squared residuals (SSR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residual_sum_of_squares) and numpy is not? One can also clearly compute the residuals by hand given the plane of best fit:

[image: function plane]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From documentation of [`numpy.linalg.lstsq()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html):

> **residuals : {(), (1,), (K,)} ndarray**
>
> ... If the rank of a is `< N` or `M <= N`, this is an empty array. ...

The rank of your matrix is 1.

---

**NOTE:** What you think are "missing" residuals can be found using `numpy` as well (you do not need other packages):

```
residuals = y - np.dot(A, model_parameters)
```

Comment: Okay, I see I only have one linearly independent column vector (i.e. `rank = 1`), however, why is Numpy refusing to give me the residuals at all? They clearly exist. Is there a mathematical reason for not providing the residuals? Or is this a faulty design choice by Numpy? You are able to find the residuals by hand and through using other implementations, such as Statsmodels.

Comment: @DanHoynoski See https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/4438#issuecomment-36969802 If you feel like it - you can try re-open that issue or open a new one.

Comment: I have seen this post while researching the topic. I think it might be wise to open up a new issue and/or get further clarification from the developers.

Comment: @DanHoynoski The thing is that your problem is *not* *over-determined* but rather it is *under-determined* due to `rank` being 1. That is, only one of the unknowns can be determined.

Comment: But this goes against the definition of an "over-determined" system. From the wiki article (link above): "... an overdetermined system will have solutions in some cases, for example if some equation occurs several times in the system, or if some equations are linear combinations of the others." Can you explain where you are coming from because I disagree about the determinedness in your comment.

Comment: And about your updated answer. I still don't understand why Numpy is choosing not to give the residuals in the least squares call. Unless you have anything else to correct me on (please do if you can), I am going to submit an new issue to get the reasoning behind this.

Comment: The editing time ran out here, but the Numpy returned all two parameters. So your statement about "only one of the unknowns can be determined" is not correct.

Comment: @DanHoynoski See http://web.gps.caltech.edu/classes/ge193.old/lectures/Lecture2.pdf, page 7 That is what you have. Think about it you have the same equation ("quantity") equal to many values: `3*b0+20*b1=0.25;  3*b0+20*b1=0.1; 3*b0+20*b1=0.6` The "many values" (0.25, 01, 0.6) does not make it an over-determined system. What makes your system _under_-determined is the fact that you cannot solve _both_ unknowns (`b0` and `b1`) because all your equations are linearly-dependent. So, your solution is not determined. Numpy simply gave you one possible solution out of an infinity of solutions.

Comment: _"... Numpy returned all two parameters. So your statement about **"only one of the unknowns can be determined"** is not correct."_ Numpy returns "a" solution with minimal norm. This does not mean that your solution is determined.

Comment: I appreciate your help. I understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: Would it be unwise for Numpy to still return the residuals for an under-determined system given the parameters it returns?

Comment: @DanHoynoski To expand the idea of "quantity" and "many values". Let's introduce "quantity" `q=3*b0+20*b1`. Then your system is `q=0.25; q=0.1; q=0.6`. Using least squares you can find for this "over-determined" system _for `q`(!!!)_ that `q=(0.25+0.1+0.6)/3=0.3166(6)`. Yes, you have found `q` and now you can try to solve `q=0.31666=3*b0+20*b1`. Yes, you can find one value, let's say `b0` _as a function of_ `b1`. You cannot find _both_, hence you have an under-determined system for `b0` and `b1`.

Comment: _"Would it be unwise for Numpy to still return the residuals for an under-determined system?"_ I guess it's a matter of taste. Personally, I prefer to understand what is going on versus being happy that I got "an answer" and not realize that it is garbage. And ultimately, these would be the residuals for one solution out of an infinity of solutions.

Comment: *"... and not realize that it is garbage."* - Why would one of the many solutions be garbage? Because Numpy is choosing a solution that is minimizing a norm, then this is the best solution given the current data.

Comment: @DanHoynoski A solution with a minimal norm does not mean a solution that minimizes residuals. Different situations require different solutions and what you consider as a good solution for your specific problem might not be the best solution for other problems (and most likely it won't, since there is an infinity of solutions). Having a solution with a minimal norm means nothing to me (in general): I want the "best" solution - the one that minimizes the residuals but I cannot get it with an underdetermined system.

Comment: @DanHoynoski For example, setting `b1=0` could be the best solution for me because it is a "simple" solution. Let's say `b0` and `b1` are some offsets. A "simple" solution such as `b1=0` would mean that I only need to "adjust" (or shift) one data set by `b0`.

Comment: Is there no pattern with the SSR (i.e. the residuals) in this infinity solution space? You might be able to get the true minimum, but can you get close? (I'm going off topic here, so this will be my last subject related question)